# Automatically solve an equation of `pt` for `ncp`

Tags: r, function, statistics

I wonder if it is possible to efficiently change  `ncp` in the **below code** such that `x` becomes **.025** and **.975** (within rounding error).

```
x <- pt(q = 5, df = 19, ncp = ?)
```

### ----------

**Clarification**

`q = 5` and `df = 19` (above) are just two hypothetical numbers, so `q` and `df` could be any other two numbers. What I expect is a function / routine, that takes `q` and `df` as input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong with `uniroot`?

```
f <- function (ncp, alpha) pt(q = 5, df = 19, ncp = ncp) - alpha

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
curve(f(ncp, 0.025), from = 5, to = 10, xname = "ncp", main = "0.025")
abline(h = 0)
curve(f(ncp, 0.975), from = 0, to = 5, xname = "ncp", main = "0.975")
abline(h = 0)
```

[image]

So for `0.025` case, the root lies in `(7, 8)`; for `0.975` case, the root lies in `(2, 3)`.

```
uniroot(f, c(7, 8), alpha = 0.025)$root
#[1] 7.476482

uniroot(f, c(2, 3), alpha = 0.975)$root
#[1] 2.443316
```

### ---------

**(After some discussion...)**

OK, now I see your ultimate goal. You want to implement this equation solver as a function, with input `q` and `df`. So they are unknown, but fixed. They might come out of an experiment.

Ideally if there is an analytical solution, i.e., `ncp` can be written as a formula in terms of `q`, `df` and `alpha`, that would be so great. However, this is not possible for t-distribution.

Numerical solution is the way, but `uniroot` is not a great option for this purpose, as it relies on **"plot - view - guess - specification"**. The answer by *loki* is also crude but with some improvement. It is a grid search, with fixed step size. Start from a value near 0, say `0.001`, and increase this value and check for approximation error. We stop when this error fails to decrease.

This really initiates the idea of numerical optimization with Newton-method or quasi-Newton method. In 1D case, we can use function `optimize`. It does variable step size in searching, so it converges faster than a fixed step-size searching.

Let's define our function as:

```
ncp_solver <- function (alpha, q, df) {
  ## objective function: we minimize squared approximation error
  obj_fun <- function (ncp, alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df) {
    (pt(q = q, df = df, ncp = ncp) - alpha) ^ 2
    }
  ## now we call `optimize`
  oo <- optimize(obj_fun, interval = c(-37.62, 37.62), alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df)
  ## post processing
  oo <- unlist(oo, use.names = FALSE)  ## list to numerical vector
  oo[2] <- sqrt(oo[2])  ## squared error to absolute error
  ## return
  setNames(oo, c("ncp", "abs.error"))
  }
```

Note, `-37.62` / `37.62` is chosen as lower / upper bound for `ncp`, as it is the maximum supported by t-distribution in R (read `?dt`).

For example, let's try this function. If you, as given in your question, has `q = 5` and `df = 19`:

```
ncp_solver(alpha = 0.025, q = 5, df = 19)
#         ncp    abs.error
#7.476472e+00 1.251142e-07
```

The result is a named vector, with `ncp` and absolute approximation error.

Similarly we can do:

```
ncp_solver(alpha = 0.975, q = 5, df = 19)
#         ncp    abs.error
#2.443347e+00 7.221928e-07
```

### ----------

**Follow up**

> Is it possible that in the function `ncp_solver()`, `alpha` takes a `c(.025, .975)` together?

Why not wrapping it up for a "vectorization":

```
sapply(c(0.025, 0.975), ncp_solver, q = 5, df = 19)

#                  [,1]         [,2]
#ncp       7.476472e+00 2.443347e+00
#abs.error 1.251142e-07 7.221928e-07
```

> How come 0.025 gives upper bound of confidence interval, while 0.975 gives lower bound of confidence interval? Should this relationship reversed?

No surprise. By default `pt` computes lower tail probability. If you want the "right" relationship, set `lower.tail = FALSE` in `pt`:

```
ncp_solver <- function (alpha, q, df) {
  ## objective function: we minimize squared approximation error
  obj_fun <- function (ncp, alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df) {
    (pt(q = q, df = df, ncp = ncp, lower.tail = FALSE) - alpha) ^ 2
    }
  ## now we call `optimize`
  oo <- optimize(obj_fun, interval = c(-37.62, 37.62), alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df)
  ## post processing
  oo <- unlist(oo, use.names = FALSE)  ## list to numerical vector
  oo[2] <- sqrt(oo[2])  ## squared error to absolute error
  ## return
  setNames(oo, c("ncp", "abs.error"))
  }
```

Now you see:

```
ncp_solver(0.025, 5, 19)[[1]]  ## use "[[" not "[" to drop name
#[1] 2.443316

ncp_solver(0.975, 5, 19)[[1]]
#[1] 7.476492
```

### --------

## Bug report and fix

I was reported that the above `ncp_solver` is unstable. For example:

```
ncp_solver(alpha = 0.025, q = 0, df = 98)
#      ncp abs.error 
#-8.880922  0.025000
```

But on the other hand, if we double check with `uniroot` here:

```
f <- function (ncp, alpha) pt(q = 0, df = 98, ncp = ncp, lower.tail = FALSE) - alpha
curve(f(ncp, 0.025), from = -3, to = 0, xname = "ncp"); abline(h = 0)
```

[image]

```
uniroot(f, c(-2, -1.5), 0.025)$root
#[1] -1.959961
```

So there is clearly something wrong with `ncp_solver`.

Well it turns out that we can not use too big bound, `c(-37.62, 37.62)`. If we narrow it to `c(-35, 35)`, it will be alright.

Also, to avoid tolerance problem, we can change objective function from squared error to absolute error:

```
ncp_solver <- function (alpha, q, df) {
  ## objective function: we minimize absolute approximation error
  obj_fun <- function (ncp, alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df) {
    abs(pt(q = q, df = df, ncp = ncp, lower.tail = FALSE) - alpha)
    }
  ## now we call `optimize`
  oo <- optimize(obj_fun, interval = c(-35, 35), alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df)
  ## post processing and return
  oo <- unlist(oo, use.names = FALSE)  ## list to numerical vector
  setNames(oo, c("ncp", "abs.error"))
  }

ncp_solver(alpha = 0.025, q = 0, df = 98)
#          ncp     abs.error 
#-1.959980e+00  9.190327e-07
```

Damn, this is a pretty annoying bug. But relax now.

## Report on getting warning messages from `pt`

I also receive some report on annoying warning messages from `pt`:

```
ncp_solver(0.025, -5, 19)
#          ncp     abs.error 
#-7.476488e+00  5.760562e-07
#Warning message:
#In pt(q = q, df = df, ncp = ncp, lower.tail = FALSE) :
#  full precision may not have been achieved in 'pnt{final}'
```

I am not too sure what is going on here, but meanwhile I did not observe misleading result. Therefore, I decide to suppress those warnings from `pt`, using `suppressWarnings`:

```
ncp_solver <- function (alpha, q, df) {
  ## objective function: we minimize absolute approximation error
  obj_fun <- function (ncp, alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df) {
    abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = q, df = df, ncp = ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha)
    }
  ## now we call `optimize`
  oo <- optimize(obj_fun, interval = c(-35, 35), alpha = alpha, q = q, df = df)
  ## post processing and return
  oo <- unlist(oo, use.names = FALSE)  ## list to numerical vector
  setNames(oo, c("ncp", "abs.error"))
  }

ncp_solver(0.025, -5, 19)
#          ncp     abs.error 
#-7.476488e+00  5.760562e-07
```

OK, quiet now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two `while` loops like this:

```
i <- 0.001
lowerFound <- FALSE
while(!lowerFound){
  x <- pt(q = 5, df = 19, ncp = i)
  if (round(x, 3) == 0.025){
    lowerFound <- TRUE
    print(paste("Lower is", i))
    lower <- i
  } else {
    i <- i + 0.0005
  }
}

i <- 0.001
upperFound <- FALSE
while(!upperFound){
  x <- pt(q = 5, df = 19, ncp = i)
  if (round(x, 3) == 0.975){
    upperFound <- TRUE
    print(paste("Upper is ", i))
    upper <- i
  } else {
    i <- i + 0.0005
  }
}

c(Lower = lower, Upper = upper)
#  Lower  Upper 
# 7.4655 2.4330
```

Of course, you can adapt the increment in `i <- i + ....`  or change the check `if (round(x,...) == ....)` to fit this solution to your specific needs of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there is now a one-line solution to this problem using the `conf.limits.nct()` function in the MBESS package.

```
install.packages("MBESS")
library(MBESS)

result <- conf.limits.nct(t.value = 5, df = 19)
result

$Lower.Limit
[1] 2.443332

$Prob.Less.Lower
[1] 0.025

$Upper.Limit
[1] 7.476475

$Prob.Greater.Upper
[1] 0.025
```

`$Lower.Limit` is the result where `pt = 0.975`

`$Upper.Limit` is the result where `pt = 0.025`

```
pt(q=5,df=19,ncp=result$Lower.Limit)
[1] 0.975
> pt(q=5,df=19,ncp=result$Upper.Limit)
[1] 0.025
```